# CRM 2015, 'Xrm' namespace not found

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, xrm

I can't get CRM 2015 sdk working. I keep getting this error:

> The type or namespace name 'Xrm' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I am using .NET 4.5.2.  All threads I've found online were about this upgrade of .NET. I find it weird that I managed to run the same code on Windows Server 2003, without any errors.  Since there is no Windows Identity Foundation for WS 2003 I cannot connect to any CRM server.

But in Windows 8.1 I encountered this issue.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23190

Comment: Solved. I used the .dll files Microsoft.Xrm,Sdk and Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Proxy from the CRM SDK 2013

Answer (score 0):

Use the .dlls file from the CRM SDK 2013.

*Answer given by Cosmin Plesa in the comments*

Answer (score 0):

There is no compatibility issue of CRM 2015 SDK with your windows version and either your .Net Framework version.

Download the [SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44567) and reference on you project the local .dll files that you can find inside SDK>**bin** folder